# Syntax for parsing the Nth item from JSON array using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen many JQuery examples that make use of $.each to loop through a JSON array.  However, what need to do is individually grab items 0 - 3 and pass them to another function called "Search".  Here's what I've come up with.

```
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:61741/binggame/play?cat=Body%20Parts", {
        tags: "English",
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"

    },


function (data) {

    Search(data.items[0], "Box1_Image");
    Search(data.items[1], "Box2_Image");
    Search(data.items[2], "Box3_Image");
    Search(data.items[3], "Box4_Image");
});
```

I'm fairly certain that data.items[] is not the correct syntax.

Here's a sample of my JSON:

```
{"nouns":[
    {
        "ID":26,
        "Category":"Body Parts",
        "English":"muscle",
        "Pinyin":"gei yUk",
        "Image1":null,
        "Audio1":null
    },
    {
        "ID":27,
        "Category":"Body Parts",
        "English":"neck",
        "Pinyin":"gen",
        "Image1":null,
        "Audio1":null
    },
    {
        "ID":28,
        "Category":"Body Parts",
        "English":"nose",
        "Pinyin":"bei",
        "Image1":null,
        "Audio1":null
    },
    {
        "ID":29,
        "Category":"Body Parts",
        "English":"rib",
        "Pinyin":"lat gwt",
        "Image1":null,
        "Audio1":null
    }
]}
```

For this sample, the value of data.items[0] should be "muscle", data.items[1] should be "neck", data.items[2] should be "nose" and data.items[3] should be "rib".

Can someone point out to me what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can someone point out to me what I've done wrong?

To start, there is no property names `items` in your JSON.

---

If you want to get `"muscle"`: `data.nouns[0].English`

If you want to get `"neck"`: `data.nouns[1].English`

and so on:

```
function (data) {

    Search(data.nouns[0].English, "Box1_Image");
    Search(data.nouns[1].English, "Box2_Image");
    Search(data.nouns[2].English, "Box3_Image");
    Search(data.nouns[3].English, "Box4_Image");
});
```

or, to stay DRYer:

```
function (data) {
    var nouns = data.nouns;

    function getNoun(i) {
        return nouns[i].English;
    }

    Search(getNoun(0), "Box1_Image");
    Search(getNoun(1), "Box2_Image");
    Search(getNoun(2), "Box3_Image");
    Search(getNoun(3), "Box4_Image");
});
```

or better still:

```
function (data) {
    var nouns = data.nouns;

    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        Search(nouns[i].English, 'Box' + (i+1) + '_Image');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Somehow I got the mistaken impression that "items" was part of the JQuery syntax.  Your answer makes the correct syntax very clear to me now.  +1 for cleaning up my code and making it more DRY.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are manipulating the list in the nouns property and in that case it would be:

```
for (var i = 0, l = data.nouns.length; i < l; i++) {
    Search(data.nouns[i].English, 'Box' + (i + 1) + '_Image');
}
```

Comment: Not quite - he needs the `.English` property.